# Find the value of y in $11y \equiv 14 \pmod{19}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find the value of $y$ in $11y \equiv 14 \pmod{19}$.

My issue is not with finding a solution.  Using the Euclidean algorithm and Bezout's identity I get a final expression of: $$(11)(7)(14) - (19)(4)(14) = 14$$ which equals $$(11)(98) - (19)(56) = 14$$

which would imply $y = 98$, which checks out.  But the text got a solution of $y= 3$. Now performing a modular operation on $98$, I do get $98\equiv 3 \pmod{19}$ but is that just coincidental?  I ask because I am under the impression that if I want to satisfy the expression : $$11y - 19b = 14$$ then I also need to have a value to pair with $y=3$. Doing high school algebra, I can find $b=1$, but shouldn't I be able to find the $b=1$ value through the same modular process?  or is it a case that I can end up with a bunch of congruences between the two variables and I have to just mix and match until I find a pair that satisfy the expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

What is the inverse of $11$ in $\mathbb Z/19\mathbb Z$ ?

Comment: innvers is $7$ by Bezout

Comment: And thus $$11y\equiv 14\pmod {19} \implies \underbrace{7\cdot 11}_{\equiv 1\pmod{19}}y\equiv 7\cdot 14\pmod {19}$$$$\implies  y\equiv 98\pmod {19}\implies y\equiv 3\pmod {19}$$@dc3rd

Comment: Hmm,  so my thinking behind the relationship was correct,  I really have to be mindful of multiplicative inverses.  But what about the other term: $$(19)(56)$$?  shouldn't i be able to find a congruence to that term that could satisfy $$11y - 19b = 14$$?

Comment: what do you mean by $(19)(56)$ ? I don't understand your questions. @dc3rd

Comment: well in solvimg for the Bezout coefficients i.e $y = 98$ and $b = 56$ shouldn't there be an analogous solution to the $b$ coefficient as there is to the $y$ one?  So shouldn't i be able to "reduce" $56$ down to some modulus that allows me to satisfy $11y - 19b = 14$ with variables $y = 3$ and $b = ?$

Comment: I think you make some confusion since Bezout doesn't tell you that there is $y$ and $b$ s.t. $11y-19b=14$ since $\gcd(11,19)=1\neq 14$. So you can't find the $b$ using euclid algorithm.

Comment: really???  then I am a little confused then.  I thought Bezout said that $ax + by = gcd(a,b)$ always has a solution. So with that being the case,  wouldn't multiplying through by a scalar $\frac{c}{gcd(a,b)}$ provide me with another set of solutions?

Comment: Yes, Bezout says $ax+by=\gcd(a,b)$ has a solution. But $14\neq \gcd(11,19)$, that's why you don't even know if there is $y,b$ s.t. $11y-19b=14$. The only thing that Bezout says it's that there is a solution at $11y-19b=1$, no more.

Comment: And what is the inverse of 3019 modulo 15486571? It seems you can do it immediately....

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $$y\equiv \frac{14}{11}\equiv \frac{33}{11}\equiv3 \mod 19$$

Comment: I am not sure I follow. .....

Comment: The writing $\frac{14}{11}$ and $\frac{33}{11}$ are really abusive, but it's the idea.

Comment: @dc3rd: What Dr. Sonnhard wants to says is that $33\equiv 14\mod 19$ (since $33=1\cdot 19+14$).

Comment: @dc3rd Do not expect explanations from the "Dr."

Answer (score 1):

You correctly found that $y \equiv 98 \pmod{19}$ satisfies the congruence $11y \equiv 14 \pmod{19}$.

What does that mean?

It means that for each integer $t$, $y = 98 + 19t$ satisfies the congruence $11y \equiv 14 \pmod{19}$.  In particular, if $t = -5$, we obtain $y = 3$.  Hence, $3$ satisfies the congruence $11y \equiv 14 \pmod{19}$.  Therefore, it is not coincidental that $98 \equiv 3 \pmod{19}$.

How can we verify that $3$ is a solution to the congruence $11y \equiv 14 \pmod{19}$?

The set of solutions to the congruence is the set of integers that satisfy the equation $11y = 14 + 19s$ for some integer $s$.  Clearly, if $s = 1$, then $y = 3$, so $y \equiv 3 \pmod{19}$.  The value $y = 98$ that you found comes from setting $s = 56$ since $11 \cdot 98 = 1078 = 56 \cdot 19 + 14$.

The author of your text probably chose to represent the equivalence class 
$$y \equiv 3 \pmod{19} = \{y \in \mathbb{Z} \mid y = 3 + 19s, s \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$
with $3$ rather than $98$ or some other representative since $3$ is the only representative of this equivalence class that satisfies the inequalities $0 \leq y < 19$.

If $n$ is a positive integer, it is standard practice to represent a congruence class
$$m \pmod{n} = \{m \in \mathbb{Z} \mid m = m + kn, k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$
with the representative $m'$ that satisfies the inequalities $0 \leq m' < n$.

Comment: I see where I went wrong in my thought process.  I fell into the trap of expecting a specific $s$ for my solved $b$. eventhough it is the case there is a specific $s$ it doesn't come from the euclidean algorithm.  if anything $y$ is dependent on the $s$ chosen.  thanks for the clarification